# What is wrong with this counterexample to primality test assuming GRH?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

From [SMOOTH NUMBERS: COMPUTATIONAL NUMBER THEORY AND BEYOND Andrew Granville pp.13-14](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.5030&rep=rep1&type=pdf):

> **2j. Lenstra’s polynomial time test as to whether an integer that is conjecturally prime, is rigorously squarefree.**
>   If $n > 32$ ... (note that if the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis (GRH) holds and $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for all $a < 2 \log^2{n}$ $(*)$ then $n$ is indeed prime).

Searching the web for about 20 minutes couldn't find reference for this.

> Q1 What is a reference for this claim?

Alleged counter example:

Let $k=9981$ and $n=(6k+1)(12k+1)(18k+1)=1288666276813009$.

$n$ has only three prime factors coming from the closed form
form and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number#Discovery) it is Carmichael number. By the definition, the
smallest $a$ s.t. $a^{n-1} \ne 1 \pmod{n}$ is $6k+1$, which is larger
than the RHS of $(*)$.

Pari session:

```
? k=9981;n=(6*k+1)*(12*k+1)*(18*k+1)
%28 = 1288666276813009
? for(a=1,2*log(n)^2,b=Mod(a,n)^(n-1);if(b!=1,print(a)));
? \\nothing printed
```

> Q2 What is wrong with the alleged counterexample?

**Added**

Voters to close are recommended to read on meta [Is it frowned upon to answer a question and vote to close?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1700/is-it-frowned-upon-to-answer-a-question-and-vote-to-close)

Comment: I don't know what the issue is but here is the source of these types of bounds. Maybe there is some hypothesis, like n has to be sufficiently large. http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-191/S0025-5718-1990-1023756-8/

Comment: Maybe you don't want $n$ to be a Carmichael number either.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch According to the conjecture about prime triplets, there are infinitely many triplets of this kind, so n can be arbitrary large. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch If you don't want n to be Carmichael number then this shouldn't be called primality test IMHO.

Comment: Granville have hypothesis $n > 32$, not sure if this applies for the rest.

Comment: Bach's theorem says that (under GRH) if $G$ is a proper subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^*$, there exists $a \notin G, 1 < a \le 2(\log n)^2$. If $n$ is not Carmichael $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ is a proper subgroup. If you don't like that, you can use $a^{(n-1)/2}(a|n) \equiv 1 \pmod n$ (Solovay-Stassen) or complain to Granville for making a silly mistake.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch No problem spamming Granville, but what to ask him (except reference)? He quotes Lenstra, not Bach.

Comment: To me he does not appear to quote Lenstra, the way I read it is just a side-remark (that might be imprecise).

Comment: @quid Thanks. I think the question matches the paper. Granville might give "interpretation" of Lenstra algorithm.

Comment: I do not quite understand; as far as I can see; the parenthetical remark is not part of the description or verification of Lenstra's algorithm.

Comment: @quid Might be wrong, but the bold title **2j. Lenstra’s polynomial time test as to whether an integer that is conjecturally prime** suggests to me so.

Comment: @joro: As Felipe said, Granville made a silly mistake. He is an expert on Carmichael numbers, but he is also human (errare humanum est). This question should be closed.

Comment: @GHfromMO Don't mind it closed at all, vote as you wish. What is a reference for a correct statement of the claim?

Comment: @joro: If you read Granville's paragraph carefully, you will see that the part in parentheses is irrelevant for testing the square-freeness of $n$. That is, the statement in the first line is correct (without GRH), and its full proof is given in the paragraph.

Comment: This question is based on reading very literally a carelessly worded sentence from a paper.  There is already a good answer pointing out what was intended.  The particular questions raised here do not strike me as showing much "research effort."  Therefore I am voting to close this.

Comment: Please do not close this question by downvotes, because my answer contains useful information (I hope).

Comment: @GHfromMO One cannot close a question by down-votes. Closing and up/downvoting are completely unrelated.

Comment: @quid: You are right. I meant "by votes to close" instead of "by downvotes".

Comment: @Lucia Do you mean I should not **read very literally**? Like switching inequalities?

Comment: I've had to delete two comments from this thread that were flagged as rude/offensive. May I please ask commenters to refrain from getting too personal.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I believe Voloch answered this question and then deleted the answer, would someone 10K+ confirm this?

Comment: Yes, he answered, and then deleted the answer a short time ago.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Thanks, just to make sure my last edit of the question makes sense.

Comment: @joro You objected that I both answered and voted to close. Although I disagree that I can't do both, I decided to respect your wishes. Since I stand by my vote to close, I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a revised version of my original answer. I fixed some inconsistencies and made the text more readable.

The correct statement is given by the deterministic Miller-Rabin test coupled with an estimate of Bach under GRH. Let us follow Sections 10.2 and 10.5 of [Shoup: A computational introduction to number theory and algebra (version 2)](http://shoup.net/ntb/). Let $n$ be an odd integer, and write $n-1$ as $2^st$ with $t$ odd. Consider

$$ L_n':=\left\{a\in\mathbb{Z}_n^\times:\ a^{2^s t}=1\quad\text{and}\quad a^{2^{r+1}t}=1\Longrightarrow a^{2^rt}=\pm 1\quad\text{for}\quad 0\leq r<s \right\} $$

For $n$ prime, $L_n'$ equals $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$. For $n$ composite, the proof of Theorem 10.3 in [Shoup's book](http://shoup.net/ntb/) shows that $L_n'$ generates a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n^\times$. Combining these statements with Theorem 2 of [Bach](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-191/S0025-5718-1990-1023756-8/S0025-5718-1990-1023756-8.pdf), we get:

**Theorem 1.** Assume GRH. Let $n$ be an odd integer. Then $n$ is composite if and only if there is $1<b<2\log^2 n$ such that $b$ mod $n$ lies outside $L_n'$.

Using Theorem 1.1 of [Lamzouri-Li-Soundararajan](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3595) in place of Bach's result, we get the following stronger version:

**Theorem 2.** Assume GRH. Let $n>3000$ be an odd integer. Then $n$ is composite if and only if there is $1<b<\log^2 n$ such that either $b\mid n$, or $b$ mod $n$ lies outside $L_n'$.

**Added.** The OP wanted more specific answers to his questions Q1 and Q2. Here they are:

Q1: The quoted paragraph without the parentheses gives a complete proof for the square-free test, so Granville's paper can be taken as a reference (although I am sure Lenstra wrote this down earlier in some form). The part in parentheses is false, so there is no reference for it. A corrected version for this part is given above, and a reference for it is [Shoup's book](http://shoup.net/ntb/).

Q2: There is nothing wrong with the quoted counterexample. It is a genuine counterexample to the part in parentheses, which shows in particular that the part in parentheses is false.

Comment: Thanks. But Granville quotes/interprets **Lenstra's** test, not yours or I am missing something?

Comment: Why should I read 1994 book when the paper according to metadata is from 2006?

Comment: @joro at the risk of repeating myself, why do you think that parenthetical statement is part of the test? To me it just complements the preceding explanatory remark that the imposed condition (not the one you quote)  is unlikely to hold for non-primes as a slightly stronger one even (allegedly) characterizes primes. I think it is really just a tangential remark that came out imprecise.

Comment: @quid I believe I quoted the paper correctly, don't know why the paper claims so and asked about this.

Comment: @joro yes you quoted it correctly, but the part you quote is not part of the test but a side-remark, that happens to be imprecise. Yet the parenthetical  could just be omitted without affecting the rest.

Comment: @quid my question is not about primality test under GRH, it is something else. Please read again.

Comment: @joro what type of answer do you expect? re Q1: the claim is not correct. re Q2: nothing, as far as I can see. The answer here makes an attempt to write something similar in spirit to the incorrect side-remark; other attempts were made by Voloch. In any case it has no real bearing on the Lenstra algorithm discussed there. In that sense your initial comments make no sense to me.

Comment: @quid I expect answer to Q1 and/or Q2, not speculations about what primality test under GRH is.

Comment: @joro: See my added section. Also, note that I did not speculate about what a primality test under GRH is. Instead, I gave a valid primality test under GRH which  corrects Granville's claim in the parentheses (I am sure Granville had this corrected statement in mind in the first place, feel free to ask him about this).

Comment: @joro: One more thought. Granville's paper is a summary of earlier results (or so it seems), much like a textbook. So going back to an earlier paper or book (like Koblitz) makes perfect sense.

Comment: GH, your revision as of now appears sound answer to me (the initial revision had nothing to do with the question IMHO). Thanks.

Comment: Though your claim "there is no citable reference for a false claim" is quite controversial.

Comment: @joro: I told an opinion. Of course, it is possible that Granville cited an erroneous source, but given that Granville was who proved that there are infinitely many Carmichael numbers, I find this rather unlikely. It is much more likely that he was writing his notes quickly and made a silly mistake.

Comment: GH, about the false reference I meant in general, not in this case. Hypothetically it is possible Granville cited erroneous source, but I doubt this is the case here.